# Check if a url exists

Tags: android, http, url

I have developed a code to check if a url exists but it is not doing anything, could you please point out my mistake?

```
public void main(String s[]) {
    String URLName  = "http://www.google.com/";
    Log_in uRLExists = new Log_in();
    uRLExists.checkURLExists(URLName);
}

public void checkURLExists(String URLName) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();

        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

        if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "URL Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "URL not Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException unknownHostException){
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?, try adding a printStackTrace to your catch(UnknownHostException unknownHostException){
    } also

Comment: I did nothing changed though, no I am not getting any exceptions

Comment: `main()` method? Is it Android application?

Comment: Yes, it is an android app

Comment: Good point, overlooked the main(), which is odd... Can you post your activity code as well?  AFAIK main() will never be called in an Android app.

Comment: What is `Log_in`? Is it class inside activity?

Comment: No it is my main activity, I think it is as Sector95 says, I am using UI thread

Answer (score 2):

On the Toasts, assuming this code is within an Activity, change `getBaseContext()` to `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: sorry but still nothing appears, I am pretty sure my mistake is something so silly

Comment: If you're truly not throwing an exception, then I'm assuming it has something to do with your Toast calls, since the rest of your code *appears* solid to me.  Try `Log.d("URL Result", "URL Exists");` and `Log.d("URL Result", "URL does not exist.");` to verify you're actually making it into your if statement.  It should log to LogCat within Android Studio when debugging.

Comment: It throws this exception `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, and yes i have the following permission on my manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and have connected to wifi as well

Comment: That's because you're opening a network connection on the UI thread. Check out the `AsyncTask` class, and look up networking in the Android Developer guide.

Comment: I think you are right, thank I'll try to change that

Answer (score 1):

You can't do Network on MainThread. You are most likely getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You should call `checkURLExists()` from a worker thread.

You could use AsyncTask class to do a network operation.

```
public class UrlChecker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        // Check your URL here
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean exists) {
        // Do something with your result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not call connect method.
After con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
Add this: con.connect();

BTW,  you should put the code in a new thread. Don't run it on the main thread, it will hang the App.

Try this:

```
        new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(customURL);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                    con.connect();
                    Log.i(TAG, "con.getResponseCode() IS : " + con.getResponseCode());
                    if(con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Sucess");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail");
                }
            }

        }.start();
```